# Multiple columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

[image: Multiple columns]

I want multiple columns, I surfed to find a solution. But as in the attached picture, I need to generate a report that can give category (group 1 wise group 2 data), but I need the group 1 to be on the center and not as the group data in a column format. So I know the group 2 data is a summary of what I require for each area,  i.e group 1 content.

How can I set the group 1 to show the area name in the center without the multiple column format where as the group 2 in multiple column format.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Format Groups with multiple columns", all groups will be put in that style. There are a few work-around solutions available to you:

1. If the groups can be separated by page breaks, then the Group Footer 2 could be set to add a "New page after" and your heading for Group Header 1 could be put in the Page Header instead.
2. Use a sub-report where the Groups are formatted with multiple columns, but not in the main report.
3. You can put the contents of Group Footer 2 into the details section and suppress it unless it has reached the end of the group. The Groups would no longer need to be formatted for multiple columns, and the Group Footer 2 would need to be suppressed permanently. You could suppress the details section based on either:

   a. Create a running total (count) for your record number (reset on group change) and compare it to a summary (count) by the group. The suppression would then be:

   ```
   {#RecordNumber} <> COUNT({field},{group})
   ```

   b. You could just check the next records based on what your Group(/s) is(/are), although logic relating to nulls may be an issue depending on the data and number of Groups you're working with:

   ```
   Not(NextIsNull({group})) AND Next({group}) = {group}
   ```